# Rails pluck get carrierwave url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, carrierwave

I got a `Book` modal, and book has one `cover`(used by `carrierwave`). 
Then I got anther modal it contain books called `Good`

So, in the controller I need to load all `book.coverl` first to prevent `N+1` query.

Here is code

```
#@course_goods contain a lots of column, include BookContent.id, too
all_book = BookContent.where(id: @course_goods[:contents_goods].map{|i| i["book_content_id"]}).pluck_all(:id,:cover).map{|b| [b["id"], b["cover"]]}.to_h
```

The result will like this

```
{
     3 => "book_content_cover.jpg",
     4 => "book_content_cover.jpg",
     5 => nil,
     6 => nil,
     ...
```

However, I want the cover became `cover.url` instead of `cover_identifier`

Like this

```
{
    1 => "http://...jpg",
    2 => "http://...jpg"
    3 => "http://...jpg"
}
```

### Update

I figure it out

```
all_book = BookContent.where(id: @course_goods[:contents_goods].map{|i| [i["book_content_id"]]})
a_hash ={}
all_book.each do |i|
 a_hash[i[:id]] = i.cover.url
end
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

If do this what appears?

```
all_book = BookContent.where(id: @course_goods[:contents_goods].map{|i,k| [i["book_content_id"], k]})
```

Comment: It will return an array, and it contain all of  column of `BookContent `, include id, name and cover. But how do I only get the hash table which is `id` to `cover.url`?

Comment: I figure it out and updated that, is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

For those who use fog-aws, here is how I did it:

```ruby
s3 = Fog::Storage.new(
  provider: 'AWS', region: ENV['S3_REGION'],
  aws_access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], aws_secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
)
directory = s3.directories.new(key: ENV['S3_BUCKET'])
path = directory.files.new(
  key: "your/key.jpg"
).url(Time.now + 1000)
```